# How to get selected value from mono Gtk.ComboBox?

Tags: combobox, mono, gtk

How do I get the selected value (either the string, or an int reference) from a Gtk.ComboBox in mono? All I can find is stuff about using iterators. Why isn't there a function to simply fetch the value (or is there)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For (int) index you can use:

```
comboBox.Active;
```

and for text:

```
comboBox.ActiveText;
```

Comment: First value is 0 or 1?

Comment: First is 0. (text added to omit char limit).

Answer (score 4):

to get the selected value in a GTK+ combo box I used:

```
 TreeIter tree;
 comboBox.GetActiveIter(out tree);
 TreeModel = comboBox.Model ();
 String selectedText = (String) comboBox.Model.GetValue (tree, 0);
```

"comboBox" is the GTK combo box.
I hope this will help.